# How would you structure this smart contract: ownership percentages, ERC777, UI flow?

Tags: contract-design, user-experience, erc-777

I'm trying to get familiar with the patterns in designing Solidity smart contracts.

For example, say I'm trying to model a **Mall** with multiple **Restaurants** in it. Each restaurant can have multiple **Owners** owning a stake in the restaurant. The person with the greater than 50% ownership is the main owner of the restaurant. Each restaurant has a valuation. People trade ownership of the restaurants using a MALL token.

[image: Show the main model entities: a mall which contains restaurants which are owned by multiple people]

Now assume that I have the following user interface.

- (1) "Bidders" can see a list of owners of a restaurant and can make an offer to buy all or some of an owner's share of the restaurant. They can bid at market value for the share or above/below market value
- (2) The owner can see various bids and choose to accept/reject the offers.

[image: 2 user interfaces for making bids and accepting/rejecting them]

With an ERC20 token, you would need to make an allow transaction followed by the actual transaction so I thought using an ERC777 would allow for an easier workflow.

The "Mall" contract could be an "operator" for the "MALL" ERC777 token.

I thought the actual bid making could happen off-chain.

When a bid is accepted, that's when something is written to the blockchain (something that confirms that the owner is willing to sell their share, how much and for what value).

Otherwise I feel it would become too messy - if the bidder had to transfer tokens with each bid, then the owner could purposely not respond to them and tie up the funds of the bidder. Obviously I could use some kind of time calculation. But to revert the funds even with a window for the owner to accept/reject without making it too costly for myself would need some kind of UI/mechanism for the bidder to go retrieve their funds minus fees (which is not a good user experience!)

So in a nutshell I'm stuck trying to figure out what is the best way to write this smart contract without making the user interface too complicated or burdensome on the end user. I feel like this would be something very common in the Solidity world but despite a great deal of searching, I can't find the best practices on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a ERC1155 contract for each mall. ERC1155 allow the creation of multiple tokens in a single contract, which is exactly what you need. Each token is distinguished by a token `id`. I would make the first token (`id = 0`) the mall token. All other tokens created (`id >= 1`) will be the restaurants tokens.

Contract must define a `SHARE_PRECISION` global variable which will represent the number of restaurant tokens minted when creating the restaurant.

You must create a `createRestaurant` function which takes an array of tuples `(address _address, uint256 _proportion)`, where `_address` is a restaurant's shareholder and `_proportion` is a proportion of SHARE_PRECISION. When calling this function all addresses will receive `_proportion` amount of tokens. The contract must check that sum of all `_proportion` values in array = `SHARE_PRECISION`.

To trade restaurant tokens a `executeTrade` function must be created. The function must take as parameters:

- the restaurant token id (`_id`)
- the amount of restaurant tokens being bought (`_amount`)
- the cost in mall tokens (`_cost`)
- the seller address (`_seller`)
- signature from the seller (`_sig`)

Signature from the seller is generated by encoding `(_id, _amount, _cost)` and signing it with `_seller`. Then this signature is passed off-chain (through your app I suppose) to the buyer.

The buyer then calls the `executeTrade()` function passing all aforementioned parameters. `executeTrade()` initially verifies that the signature is valid, ensuring that `_id`, `_amount`, `_cost` and `_seller` are all legitimate parameters. The contract then verifies that the buyer's mall token `balance >= _cost`. It then transfers `_cost` amount of mall token to the `_seller`. Finally it transfers `_amount` amount of restaurant token `_id` from the `_seller` to the buyer.

The transferFrom function must by overridden in order to:

- make all tokens whose `id >= 1` (restaurant tokens) un-transferable unless when called from `createRestaurant()` or `executeTrade()`.

Token `id = 0` (mall token) will be freely transferable like any other ERC-20 token.

All the bid making process can be dealt with off-chain. As soon as a restaurant owner accepts a bid, he signs a message which is then sent to the buyer. The buyer then executes the transaction. Considering that `executeTrade()` already verifies the transaction, you can also override the token transfer approval, yet this would require a more in-depth explanation.

Should you need other help, feel free to ask.